# Real roots of $ 1+\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots +\frac{x^n}{n!} $

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

> Let $Q_n(x)$ be the degree $n$ polynomial
>   $$ 1+\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots +\frac{x^n}{n!} $$
>   How many real roots does the equation $Q_n(x)=0$ have?

---

My attempt:

It is obvious that $Q_n(x)$ will have all its real roots in the negative part of the real line if there is any. Also, we notice that if $n$ is odd, then there is at least one real root by the [complex conjugate root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_root_theorem). So I conjecture that there is exactly one root for $n$ odd and there is no root for $n$ even.

However, I don't know how to analyze $Q_n(x)$. All I can do is to take derivative and this does not provide more useful information. Any hint is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: hint: derivative of $Q_n(x)$ is $Q_{n-1}(x)$

Comment: @kingW3 That's enough! Thank you!

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1397428? That question is only about the case $n=6$, but the answer is for all $n$.

Comment: You can state a stronger conjecture: for $x>0$, $0<Q_0< Q_1<\cdots Q_n<e^x$ and for $x<0$, $Q_{2n-1}<e^x$, $Q_{2n}>e^x$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your conjecture is correct and it can be proved by induction.

The statement is trivially true if $n=1$. Assume that it is true for a certain $n$. If $n$ is even, then $(\forall x\in\mathbb R):Q_n(x)>0$. So, $Q_{n+1}$ is strictly increasing (note that $Q_{n+1}'(x)=Q_n(x)$) and therefore has at most one real root. But every polynomial whose degree is odd has at least one root. So, it has exactly one root.

And if $n$ is odd, then $Q_{n+1}$ first decreases and then increases. So, it has an absolute minimum, which is attained at the point $x_0$ such that $Q_n(x_0)=0$. But\begin{align}Q_{n+1}(x_0)&=Q_n(x_0)+\frac{{x_0}^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\\&=\frac{{x_0}^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\\&>0,\end{align}since $n+1$ is even and $x_0\neq0$ (since $Q_n(0)=1\neq0$).

Comment: I learned from you great answer that $Q_n(x)$ has exactly 1 root if n is even. I am not sure I get how many roots if n is odd? Thanks.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, if $n$ is odd then $Q_n$ is strictly increasing and therefore it cannot have more than one root. But a polynomial with even degree always has at least one root. So, $Q_n$ has exactly one root.

Comment: A non-induction proof is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1397473.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

if you multiply your polynomial by $\Gamma(n+1) e^{-x}$, which does not have any zeros, you get the [Incomplete Upper Gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) function $\Gamma(n+1,x)$.

Then refer [to this related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109360).

Comment: This is not much of a hint, but I will add that the Szegő curve has been previously discussed in answers on this site.

Comment: @J.M.isapoormathematician: thanks for signalling : I was actually mumbling where the entireness of $\Gamma(n+1,x)$ goes lost. Can you please detail some links to Szego curve? what is it ?  thanks