# $1+\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots +\frac{x^n}{n!}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

I am looking [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3324562/real-roots-of-1-fracx1-fracx22-fracx33-cdots-fracxn?noredirect=1) answer and maybe it's trivial but now can't understand one part of José Carlos Santos's answer. And if $n$ is odd, then $Q_{(n+1)}$ first decreases and then increases (it's trivial I know but I don't remember how can I proof that).

Comment: Because as mentioned in his answer, $Q_n$ is negative then becomes positive.

Comment: MathJax hint:  to get multicharacter subscripts, put them in braces, so Q_{(n+1)} gives $Q_{(n+1)}$.  What is it?  It is never defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that$$Q_{n+1}'(x)=Q_n(x).$$So, if $n$ is odd, $Q_n$ has a single real root, at some point $x_0$. But, again because $n$ is odd, $\lim_{x\to\infty}Q_n(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}Q_n(x)=-\infty$. So, $Q_n(x)<0$ if $x<x_0$ and $Q(x)>0$ if $x>x_0$. Therefore, $Q_{n+1}$ is decreasing on $(-\infty,x_0]$ and increasing on $[x_0,\infty)$.

Comment: Thank you professor.

Comment: When you typed $Q_n(x)<x$, did you mean $Q_n(x)<0$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Sure. I've edited my answer. Thank you.